# When export to excel from SSRS, show date in the cell while show date time in the formula bar

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

When exporting a SSRS to excel, I'm wondering if it is possible to show date in the cell of excel while showing date time in the formula bar.

Please see the attached picture as an example
[image]

In the picture, you can see the highlighted column U is shown as a date (12/26/2022) while the highlighted formula bar shows '12/26/2022 2:25:54 PM' when the user clicks on the cell. I'm wondering how to set such a date format in SSRS to do so.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the following expression:
[image]

Then set the properties of the cell as CanGrow=False and CanShrink=False, TextAlign=Left, VerticalAlign = Top. After which set the size of the cell to (1in,0.25in).The SSRS would show the cell as date (only show the date part) and excel could still show the date time part when click on it.